# Pull name for file from array when downloading using urllib

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to use the urllib library for python to pull various tools from urls stored in an array. When I go to the option to save them to a location, I would like to name each file after an entry in a separate array. Every time I try and run my code as written here:

```
import urllib

url = ["http://dw.cbsi.com/redir?ttag=restart_download_click&ptid=3001&pagetype=product_pdl&astid=2&edid=3&tag=link&siteid=4&destUrl=&onid=2239&oid=3001-2239_4-10320142&rsid=cbsidownloadcomsite&sl=en&sc=us&topicguid=security%2Fantivirus&topicbrcrm=&pid=14314872&mfgid=10044820&merid=10044820&ctype=dm&cval=NONE&devicetype=desktop&pguid=4ca3cb3823b670cd4386478c&viewguid=V4afV1BQaWxD1Ku2AKu@IeHzq6uWztjV6P2F&destUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fsoftware-files-a.cnet.com%2Fs%2Fsoftware%2F14%2F31%2F48%2F72%2Favg_free_stb_all_5961p1_177.exe%3Ftoken%3D1433990253_8690d8cb94b227464de5d6e1d59d78b4%26fileName%3Davg_free_stb_all_5961p1_177.exe","http://download.piriform.com/ccsetup506.exe"]
nameList = ["avg.exe","ccleaner.exe"]
for x in url and nameList:
    urllib.urlretrieve(x, "C:\\Users\\myName\\Desktop\\"+ nameList[x])
```

I receive the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P:\PythonProjects\programDownloader.py", line 6, in <module>
    urllib.urlretrieve(x, "C:\\Users\\myName\\Desktop\\"+ nameList[x])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: For each entry in the url array, save and name it with the file name dictated in the nameList array. So, it should save as "avg.exe" for when x=0, "ccleaner.exe" when x=1, and so forth.

Comment: `nameList[x]` you can use x as an index here. x is a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) the lists together if you want to match up corresponding elements from each list an unpack in the for loop:

```
url = ["http://dw.cbsi.com/redir?ttag=restart_download_click&ptid=3001&pagetype=product_pdl&astid=2&edid=3&tag=link&siteid=4&destUrl=&onid=2239&oid=3001-2239_4-10320142&rsid=cbsidownloadcomsite&sl=en&sc=us&topicguid=security%2Fantivirus&topicbrcrm=&pid=14314872&mfgid=10044820&merid=10044820&ctype=dm&cval=NONE&devicetype=desktop&pguid=4ca3cb3823b670cd4386478c&viewguid=V4afV1BQaWxD1Ku2AKu@IeHzq6uWztjV6P2F&destUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fsoftware-files-a.cnet.com%2Fs%2Fsoftware%2F14%2F31%2F48%2F72%2Favg_free_stb_all_5961p1_177.exe%3Ftoken%3D1433990253_8690d8cb94b227464de5d6e1d59d78b4%26fileName%3Davg_free_stb_all_5961p1_177.exe","http://download.piriform.com/ccsetup506.exe"]
nameList = ["avg.exe","ccleaner.exe"]
for x, name in zip(url,nameList):
    urllib.urlretrieve(x, "C:\\Users\\myName\\Desktop\\"+ name)
```

You are trying to index `nameList`  with the string `x` which  each string from Namelist  i.e `nameList["avg.exe"]`, that is why your code errors.

If you wanted to index you would need [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for ind, x in enumerate(url):
    urllib.urlretrieve(x, "C:\\Users\\myName\\Desktop\\"+ nameList[ind])
```

where `ind` is the index of each element in the url list.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that you are indexing the list with a string, instead of integer, as you stated in your for loop:

```
for x in url and nameList: #x is string here.
```

So you need to index your nameList with an integer instead, like follows:

```
for i, x in enumerate(url):
    urllib.urlretrieve(x, "C:\\Users\\myName\\Desktop\\"+ nameList[i])
```